# jQuery Subtract value from any value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have full duration of something divided into sections,

the user must specify the duration of all sections

i want when the user enter any duration for any section to output the remaining from the full duration no matter what if he fill the sections in order or not

```js
$(".paragraphDuration").bind('keyup', function() {
  var fullDuration = $("#fullDuration").val(),
    paragraphDuration = $(this).val();
  $(this).next('.durationSpan').text(
    $(this).val() !== '' ? (fullDuration - paragraphDuration + " min") : "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Full Duration
<input type="text" id="fullDuration" />
<p>Section1
  <input type='text' class='paragraphDuration' /><span class='durationSpan'></span>

</p>
<p>Section2
  <input type='text' class='paragraphDuration' /><span class='durationSpan'></span>

</p>
<p>Section3
  <input type='text' class='paragraphDuration' /><span class='durationSpan'></span>

</p>
```

[image: this what i did so far]

all of sections subtract from full duration !

**Update:**
the result should be like this:

```
50 - 5  = 45 min
45 - 10 = 35 min
35 - 30 = 5  min
5  - 5  = 0  min
```

is there any way to subtract from the remaining duration ?

thank you

**Update2:**
https://jsfiddle.net/vc9hryw6/

Comment: val() returns a string...You really should convert it to a number.

Comment: sorry what is the point if I convert it to a number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve your problem, you need to store cumulative values in hidden fields for each paragraph. Check the code below to see how it was implemented. Also note that this code uses your construct for a solution.

**HTML**

```
Full Duration
<input type="text" id="fullDuration" />
<p>Section1
    <input type='text' class='paragraphDuration' /><span class='durationSpan'></span>
    <input type="hidden" class="remainderDuration" value="0" />
</p>
<p>Section2
    <input type='text' class='paragraphDuration' /><span class='durationSpan'></span>
    <input type="hidden" class="remainderDuration" value="0" />
</p>
<p>Section3
    <input type='text' class='paragraphDuration' /><span class='durationSpan'></span>
    <input type="hidden" class="remainderDuration" value="0" />
</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".paragraphDuration").bind('keyup', function () {

    var fullDuration = $("#fullDuration").val();
    var paragraphDuration = $(this).val();

    // here we get the last paragraph reminder duration - if none if found we retrieve the full duration value
    var lastParagraphremainderDuration = $(this).parent().prev().children(".remainderDuration").val() != undefined ? $(this).parent().prev().children(".remainderDuration").val() : fullDuration;

    // the current reminder duration is the subtractnion of the last paragraph's one and the current paragraph duration
    var remainderDuration = lastParagraphremainderDuration - paragraphDuration;

    // store the current paragraph durantion in the current hidden field
    $(this).next().next('.remainderDuration').val(remainderDuration);

    // assign value based on the current reminder duration
    $(this).next('.durationSpan').text(
        $(this).val() !== '' ? (remainderDuration + " min") : "");
});
```

And here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12tt2342/).

Comment: No it didn't solve my problem , the result is the same with my original code :(

Comment: According to the code, paragraphDuration, doesn't change. Shouldn't it change according to the durationSpan?? Since we don't have your whole code it is hard to put this in the answer, but please check this reasoning...

Comment: please check post update , its simple but I'm not expert :D if there is no remaining it should subtract the section duration from full duration but if there is remaining which means that some of section duration was entered it should subtract the section duration from the remaining

Comment: Please, create a https://jsfiddle.net/ and post it in your question. It will be much easier to give you a proper solution :).

Comment: we must avoiding the expression of appreciation but i must say thank you so much for your help , Ingenious solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over each input field separately, using `.each()`:

```
function updateSpans(totalDuration)
{
    $('.paragraphDuration').each(function() {
        totalDuration -= $(this).val(); // update total
        $(this).next('.durationSpan').text(totalDuration);
    });
}
```

Then, you call the function like so:

```
updateSpans($("#fullDuration").val());
```

```js
function updateSpans(totalDuration)
{
    $('.paragraphDuration').each(function() {
        var currentDuration = +$(this).val();
        totalDuration -= currentDuration;
        $(this).next('.durationSpan').text(totalDuration);
    });
}

$(".paragraphDuration").bind('keyup', function() {
  var fullDuration = $("#fullDuration").val();
  updateSpans(fullDuration);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Full Duration
<input type="text" id="fullDuration" />
<p>Section1
  <input type='text' class='paragraphDuration' /><span class='durationSpan'></span>

</p>
<p>Section2
  <input type='text' class='paragraphDuration' /><span class='durationSpan'></span>

</p>
<p>Section3
  <input type='text' class='paragraphDuration' /><span class='durationSpan'></span>

</p>
```